# The Photo I capture is Low resolution, How Can I make it full Resoltion?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to built simple camera app for a project But I cant use camera camera libraries like Camera Kit. And I am not using Camera2 apis because I need backward compatibilty.

I have custom CameraPreview (extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback) class App shows realtime preview. But When I save the image in My main activity, It saves in 320x240 resoltion.

I couldnt understand why it is saving in 240p and How I can save this data in full resolution?

this is the activity where It saves the pic;

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PictureCallback {
    public final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MakePhotoActivity";
    public Camera camera;
    private int cameraId = 0;

    private Uri filerui;
    boolean visibility =false;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "hellocamera";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        //Check Permission
        FullscreenActivityPermissionsDispatcher.NeedCameraPermissinWithPermissionCheck(this);

        // do we have a camera?
        cameraId = findCamera();
        if (getBoolean()) {
            visibility=true;
            camera=Camera.open(cameraId);
            initCameraPreview();
        }
    }

    //iniitaiate preview
    public void initCameraPreview(){
        CameraPreview cameraPreview= (CameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camerePreview);
        if (visibility) {
            cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            visibility=false;
        }
        cameraPreview.init(camera);
    }

    //This is the button ı capture photos
    public void onClick(View view) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM");
        imagesFolder.getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = Helper.save();
        File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {
            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
            imageFileOS.write(data);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //  Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem myself, It turnsout I wasnt able to implement parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) correctly. If someone else encounters similar problem, This could be the source of your problem as well.